# Get corner values in Python numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to access the corner values of a numpy ndarray. I'm absolutely stumped as for methodology. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For example, from the below array I'd like a return value of array([1,0,0,5]) or array([[1,0],[0,5]]).

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  5.,  5.]])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add variety to the answers, you can get a view (not a copy) of the corner items doing:

```
corners = a[::a.shape[0]-1, ::a.shape[1]-1]
```

Or, for a generic n-dimensional array:

```
corners = a[tuple(slice(None, None, j-1) for j in a.shape)]
```

Doing this, you can modify the original array by modifying the view:

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> corners = a[tuple(slice(None, None, j-1) for j in a.shape)]
>>> corners
array([[0, 2],
       [6, 8]])
>>> corners += 1
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 3],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [7, 7, 9]])
```

**EDIT** Ah, you want a flat list of corner values... That cannot in general be achieved with a view, so @IanH's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is definitely more general, though my answer with fancy indexing does support assignment, it isn't as flexible as a view. Also, if you want a flattened version you can just do `corners.ravel()`.

Comment: @IanH But `.ravel()` will trigger a copy for most arrays, because it would require a non-constant stride.

Comment: Good point, I had missed that. You're right, that is just an inherent limitation of the problem.

Comment: I also have same requirement but my array size change. is it possible to make generic Algo

Comment: If all you wanted is to set the values in the corners, for those wondering, @Jaime's solution is an order of magnitude faster than @IanH's: `a[[0,0,-1,-1],[0,-1,0,-1]]` run at
3.61 µs ± 40.4 ns per loop, while `a[::a.shape[0]-1, ::a.shape[1]-1]` run at
492 ns ± 8.02 ns per loop.

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
A[[0,0,-1,-1],[0,-1,0,-1]]
```

where `A` is the array.

Comment: Or `data[[0, 0, -1, -1], [0, -1, -1, 0]]` for corners in clockwise order.

Answer (score 3):

Use [np.ix_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) to construct the indices.

```
>>> a
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 5.],
       [0., 0., 5., 5.]])

>>> corners = np.ix_((0,-1),(0,-1))

>>> a[corners]
array([[1., 0.],
      [0., 5.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify the corners (using negative indexes):

```
a = numpy.array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
  [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
  [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  5.],
  [ 0.,  0.,  5.,  5.]])

result = numpy.array([a[0][0],a[0][-1],a[-1][0],a[-1][-1]])
# result will contain array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  5.])

result = numpy.array([a[0][0],a[0][-1],a[-1][0],a[-1][-1]])
# result will contain array([[ 1.,  0.],
#                            [ 0.,  5.]])
```