# What is the correct way to access the columns in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I cannot figure out the following problem:

Elements that were placed at the corners of an 4X3 array are selected. The row indices of the selected items are `[0, 0]` and `[3, 3]` whereas the column indices are `[0, 2]` and `[0, 2]`. My code executes correctly but I want to know how the columns are represented. And what is the correct way to access the columns in NumPy?

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],[ 3,  4,  5],[ 6,  7,  8],[ 9, 10, 11]]) 

print 'Our array is:' 
print x 
print '\n' 

rows = np.array([[0,0],[3,3]])
cols = np.array([[0,2],[0,2]]) 
y = x[rows,cols] 

print 'The corner elements of this array are:' 
print y
```

Comment: `x[:, 2]` is the 3rd column

Comment: One of your indices seems off by one...

Comment: If you need the corners you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937699/get-corner-values-in-python-numpy-ndarray. Numpy matrices are stored as nested row arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you want.  But maybe this will help

```
In [79]: x = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],[ 3,  4,  5],[ 6,  7,  8],[ 9, 10, 11]])
```

print display of `x`:

```
In [80]: x
Out[80]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Corner selection with advanced indexing:

```
In [81]: rows = np.array([[0,0],[3,3]])
    ...: cols = np.array([[0,2],[0,2]]) 
In [83]: x[rows, cols]
Out[83]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

A `view` (see docs) of a column (last):

```
In [85]: x[:, 2]
Out[85]: array([ 2,  5,  8, 11])
```

A `view` of a row:

```
In [86]: x[2, :]
Out[86]: array([6, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],[ 3,  4,  5],[ 6,  7,  8],[ 9, 10, 11]]) 
   
print('Our array is:' ) 
print (x) 
print ('\n' )

rows = np.array([[0,0],[3,3]])
cols = np.array([[0,2],[0,2]]) 
y = x[rows,cols] # ([0,0],[3,3],[0,2],[0,2]) = (R,R,C,C) =Final Ans (0,0),(0,2),(3,0),(3,2)
   
print ('The corner elements of this array are:' )
print (y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.