# How can I create a numpy array with 1's in center and corners

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to create a numpy array like this:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

I have already created this using manual data entry. I was wondering if there is any method of doing this with as little data entry as possible.

```
my_array = np.array([[1,0,0,0,1], [0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[1,0,0,0,1]], dtype=np.float)
```

Here is my code for the manual data entry... Can this be done faster?

Comment: Show how you created the array manually

Comment: Also, what are the actual requirements? Do you want a 5x5 array always, or an array of different sizes? Is the dtype to always be `float`?

Comment: It is always a 5x5 array. and the dtype can be integers as well.

Comment: @MadPhysicist edited code with manual data entry code.

Comment: For any size rectangle this is trivially done with numpy indexing for the center and corners.

Comment: You could be a bit clever and fill in four regions of zeros starting from a grid of ones. Not a big difference.

Comment: @qwr I am a little unsure on how I would do that. Could you please provide some pointers?

Comment: Your initial array is not `int64`. It's `float`. Could you please spec out your exact requirements?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am trying to create the manual array with as little manual data entry as possible. The datatype is not significant to me. I change my manual code to have the dtype =np.float.  It is for a 5x5 array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to do this that are all very simple:

1. Manual entry, as in your question. This is nice and simple, but is not easily extensible to arbitrary sizes:

   ```
   my_array = np.array([[1,0,0,0,1],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[1,0,0,0,1]], dtype=np.float)
   ```
2. Start with ones, and fill the edges with zeros:

   ```
   my_array = np.ones((5, 5), dtype=np.float)
   my_array[0, 1:-1] = my_array[-1, 1:-1] = my_array[1:-1, 0] = my_array[1:-1, -1] = 0
   ```
3. Start with zeros and fill with ones:

   ```
   my_array = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=np.float)
   my_array[0, 0] = my_array[-1, 0] = my_array[0, -1] = my_array[-1, -1] = my_array[1:-1, 1:-1] = 1
   ```

Let's look at timings (using `%%timeit` cell magic):

Option 1:

```
9.05 µs ± 93.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Option 2:

```
7.24 µs ± 129 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Option 3:

```
3.8 µs ± 161 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Looks like doing it with zeros is the clear winner here. This is a bit surprising, given that it has a lot more work to do. We can even time [@Stardust Gogeta's variation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57382929/2988730):

```
4.2 µs ± 68.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

It is fractionally more expensive to compute the strides than to make the assignment manually, but still better than the other two options.

Let's look at how this scales with input size:

```
def zero_edges0(w, h, dtype=np.float):
    result = np.zeros((w, h), dtype=dtype)
    result[1:-1, 1:-1] = result[0, 0] = result[-1, -1] = result[0, -1] = result[-1, 0] = 1
    return result

def zero_edges1(w, h, dtype=np.float):
    result = np.ones((w, h), dtype=dtype)
    result[0, 1:-1] = result[-1, 1:-1] = result[1:-1, 0] = result[1:-1, -1] = 0
    return result
```

The timings scale quadratically with edge size, and the zeros method appears to have a slight advantage no matter how much the size increases:

[image]

The data for this chart is:

```
time = [1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000]
t_zero_edges0 = [3.32e-06, 4.15e-06, 4.2e-06, 9.61e-06, 2.05e-05, 0.00137, 0.00619, 0.161, 0.646]
t_zero_edges1 = [5.95e-06, 7.51e-06, 7.52e-06, 9.53e-06, 1.18e-05, 0.00132, 0.00601, 0.162, 0.664]
```

Finally, here is a general-purpose function for n-dimensional arrays:

```
from itertools import product

def zero_edges(shape, dtype=np.float):
    result = np.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype)
    for corner in product([0, -1], repeat=result.ndim):
        result[corner] = 1
    result[(slice(1, -1),) * result.ndim] = 1
    return result
```

The same function *could* be written with `ones`, but you would have to fill in all the `N`-dimensional edges, for `N` in the range `[0, ndim - 1)`, with zeros. It would look something like this:

```
from itertools import product, permutations

def zero_edges1(shape, dtype=np.float):
    result = np.ones(shape, dtype=dtype)
    plist = [slice(1, -1)] * (result.ndim - 1) + [0]
    for dim in range(1, result.ndim):
        for index in (0, -1):
            plist[-dim:] = [index] * dim
            for edge in permutations(plist):
                result[edge] = 0
    return result
```

I've run timings on both functions for input shapes with edges of size 10. Timings favor the more reasonable function that uses `zeros` to allocate:

Keep in mind that there may be more efficient ways to implement the second function.

Comment: **Respect** for the speed and breadth of your possible solutions view - Yet, let ask how well does the demonstrated performance comparison hold if scales grow into the ranges, where many-cells of memory-replacements will become expensive, as the matrix grows to sizes above 1E5 x 1E5 ? Is the .zeros()-based strategy still faster there? **Thanks for your kind consideration** of the update and showing the O/P the more realistic and bit more complete picture of the landscape of actual [PSPACE]-sizing and [{P|EXP}TIME]-related costs. 5x5 scales fit and sit in cache, 1E5 x 1E5 x 8B will not.

Comment: @user3666197. I had the same questions. I'm working on a multi-dimensional generalization. Will post in a few minutes...

Comment: I had some previous experience with faster mem-allocs via .zeros(), yet the core of the question is the O(n) growth of "edge" columns/rows-sizes v/s O(n^2) growth of the "center"-size for the ad-hoc modifications. On larger scales this may govern The Rules of The Game.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one thing you can do. (Corner selection drawn from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17937903/5732397).)

```
L, W = (5, 5)
m = np.zeros((L, W)) # Fill with zeros
m[1:-1, 1:-1] = m[::L-1, ::W-1] = 1 # Fill middle and corners with ones
```

Comment: `=1` is better than `fill(1)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good catch, I have edited the answer to make it simpler now.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward solution

```
def create_arr(n):
    arr = np.ones((n, n))
    arr[[0, n - 1], 1: n - 1] = 0.0
    arr[1: n - 1, [0, n - 1]] = 0.0
    return arr
```

Comment: Using fancy indexing like that is not really straightforward.

Comment: That could be made a bit simpler - `arr[1:-1,[0,-1]]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

### Let't take a ride:

Say we need size 5 x 5

```
A = np.ones( (5,5), dtype = np.int64 )
A[1:-1,0] = A[1:-1,-1] = A[0,1:-1] = A[-1,1:-1] = 0
```

And we are done.

---

```
>>> print A 
[[1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1]]
```